# Появление объекта при наведении на картинку

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на изображение показывалась ссылка? Возможно ли это сделать без `jquery hover`? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В смысле "показывалась"?

Comment: Да,что бы при наведении на картинку показывалась ссылка на картинке или что то тому подобное!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
div{position:relative}
img{float:left;}
a{position:absolute;top:50px;
left:30px;display:none}
div:hover a{display:block}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<img src="3.png" width="200" height="200" />

<a href="#">LINK </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Это из серии "Каких слов не хватает в тексте"?

Вот "нормализированый" вариант:

 <style>
  div{
   position:relative;
  }
  img{
   float:left;
  }
  a{
   position:absolute;
   top:50px;
   left:30px;
   display:none;
  }
  div:hover a{
   display:block;
  }
  img{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
  }
 </style>

 <div>
  <img src="3.png" />
  <a href="#">LINK</a>
 </div>

И [демо](http://jsfiddle.net/Tnhsb/).

Answer (score 2):

Как альтернативка - [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/vMWUB/1/)